Time vs if clauses and the differences
If clauses refer either to present or future and time clauses only to future.

I will help you provided that you work

I will help you when you work


1 where we use if clause either means if you work regularly in the present I will help you or if you start work in the future I will help you. On the other hand 2 with time clause only refers to the future time once you start working I'll help. Correct?

You are totally overthinking this.  You are forgetting context.  You are making the sentence and then worrying about the meaning.  You should start with the meaning and try to make a sentence!  Start with "What do I want to say?"  Don't start with "if I put these words together, what would it mean? If you do it like that, you ask about the meaning of unnatural and awkward expressions.  If some one uses those expressions I would ignore the grammar and guess the meaning from context because I'd assume you had made a mistake in the grammar.

It is possible to use a clause headed by when as a condition, but it does not establish that meaning with the clarity that "provided" and "if" do, and so it is used in that way in informal contexts only.  "You can go out and play when you do your homework".  That is an idiomatic utterance that does not contradict itself only because when is understood to be a condition in context.

@TimR My 1 example could mean something like like "I will help since you work (regulary) or if you work in the future I will help. I think 2 example with time clause has only a latter meaning

No. "provided that" does not mean "since".  When you say "I will help" you are making a future context, and thus the proviso, "provided that you work" [present tense] can only involve future work.  It might be minutes into the future or weeks. The utterance is silent in that regard, but  past work is not relevant.

since introduces a reason or cause.  A condition or proviso is not a reason and it is not a cause. It is a requirement.

Same if I use "will"?

@thomas  Not sure what you are asking.

If I use "if" not provided". No difference?

I will help you refers to future help by you and "if you work" establishes the condition that the person work at some time later than the time of the utterance, i.e. future work.  If you want the condition to include work-in-progress at the time of the utterance, it would be "if you are working" and even in that formulation there would be a strong implication in real-world  contexts (as distinct from petri dish contexts) of future work.  No one says the sorts of things you are saying. They are too "skeletal".

If you want "if you work" to mean "If you are someone who has a job or is otherwise industrious by nature" then you're wasting our time. We're not context-generators here. This sort of question should be closed for needing more focus.

Not quite.

"I will help you, provided that you work"
'Provided' is an 'if clause', or a conditional clause. It says nothing about timing. Your example means that, if the other party works, the speaker will help them. It is very vague and lacks context - it doesn't necessarily mean that the help will come immediately, if the help will come later, or even if the help promised is in connection with the work - it could be help with something else entirely.

"I will help you when you work"
Clauses introduced with 'when' are temporal clauses. These are about timing. Your example sounds like the help will begin with the work. Unless context said otherwise, one would assume the help is with the work. It could also mean that this is a repeat offer - that they will help whenever they work.



My 1 example could mean something like like "I will help since you work (regulary) or if you work in the future I will help. I think 2 example with time clause has only a latter meaning

This is an addition to Astralbee's good answer.

If clauses refer either to present or future and time clauses only to future.

This is the assumption behind the question, and it's wrong. (If this advice comes from an English language manual, I'd reconsider the value of the manual.)
If clauses deal with conditions, not with tenses. They are completely open ended as to time. Consider these examples:

Future - I will help you if you work tomorrow.
Present - I can help you if you work now.
Past - I would have helped you if you had worked yesterday.

English has many different markers to guide us as to the timing of the story. An if clause is not one of them.

My 1 example could mean something like like "I will help since you work (regulary) or if you work in the future I will help. I think 2 example with time clause has only a latter meaning

But what time clause are you referring to? When is not pointing to the future. We could say, I helped you when you worked yesterday. Now it's all in the past. When simply links two clauses that happen at the same time. If you're talking about I will help you, then yes, that's future. But in that case, all you're really saying is, A future tense points to the future.

@MariosAthanasiou, yes, English is my native language. I read your linked answer, and to be honest I disagree with you. The sentence in the original question makes good sense to me. (Although I wouldn't have down-voted your answer. I prefer to respond positively and up-vote answers I agree with. :) )

I don't know what you edited, but you haven't listened to me. Your whole post says, The original post is wrong. I'm saying to you, The original post was perfectly fine and needed no correction.
